# How do I stop Firefox on Ubuntu from trying to load whatever is in my clipboard when I middle-click on a non-link?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

In Firefox on Ubuntu, if I middle-click anywhere on a page that's not a link, it seems to treat whatever text is in the clipboard as a URL and tries to load it.

This is annoying, since if I either accidentally click the middle button or (more often) miss a link when trying to middle-click it, I'll either go to whatever URL is in my clipboard or get an alert saying:

> The URL is invalid and cannot be
>   loaded

Is there any way of either:

a) Disabling this functionality so that
    middle-click on a non-link does
    nothing (maybe an `about:config`
    setting?,

or

b) Making the
    functionality more intelligent, so
    that it will only try and open text
    if it looks like a URL (this seems
    like a job for a plugin).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=966627&postcount=3

In about:config - set middlemouse.contentLoadURL to false.

@corey, @therefromhere: done.

Comment: You should copy the answer here in case the link ever rots for whatever reason (thread expires, forums go down, etc).

Comment: I'll mark this accepted since it provided the right info  - if someone edits in my answer into this I'll delete my own.

Comment: Note that even if you disable that, you can still get the useful behaviour of opening what is in the clipboard: Just middle-click on the favicon (left of the URL bar); this will still work.